# Network design to learn multiple sequences of multiple categories

Tags: neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, sequence-modeling, categorical-data, network-design

For learning a single sequence, LSTM only should suffice.

However, my situation is different here. I have a **list of sequences** to learn:

- The sale volumes of 12 months, these are the sequences

And **each sequence above belongs to a category**.

I'm trying it out by consider [category,sequence] as a sequential sample, the loss can be reduced to 1% but it gives wrong values in inferring real data.

The second try is considering [category,sequence] as a sample of 2 inputs:

- X1 = sequence
- X2 = category

Feed the sequence thru' LSTM layers to get **H**, and then concat with **X2**, and feed again the pair **[H,X2]** thru' some **dense layers**, the results aren't better.

Any popular solutions (network shape, network design) for learning this kind of data: **sequential data in different categories**?

Comment: You can use MathJax/latex on this site, in case you didn't know it.

Comment: i closed the question, training was done correctly, bug in inference code